# Framework Analysis: Can framework analysis (Ritchie, Spencer & O'Connor) be applied to open-ended survey question responses?

Tags: research-process, data, survey-research

**Details:**

I am building a web application for teachers and educators. The web application takes a new approach to looking at educational apps. I want to know if this approach is worthwhile, so I am going to survey some of the teachers who use it. In this survey there will be some open-ended questions regarding the benefits and drawbacks of the application. I would like to use these responses as data in my research project and I was wondering about the best way to use them. After doing a bit of looking around, it seems framework analysis might fit, though it is used primarily for interviews.

**Questions:**

1. Can framework analysis be used in this way?
2. Is there a better way of using survey responses as data?

Comment: What is framework analysis? You mention some authors but don't define it or include a link. More broadly, what do you what to say with the data? Figuring that out is usually a good first step toward deciding what to ask and how to analyze the resulting data.

Comment: Framework analysis can be broken down into five steps: familiarization (reading the responses as they come), identifying a thematic framework, indexing (identifying text that goes in each theme-frame), charting (put the text into a chart and check for sub-themes), then mapping and interpretation (essentially describing the logic used to get from data to themes).

Comment: What I want to say: There might be a better way of accessing educational applications.

Comment: I am not sure if that is the right Stack Exchange for this question. We usually talk about academia in general here, not about concrete research problems in individual fields.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about education science.

Comment: I think the question is sufficiently methodological to merit leaving open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can. If you need to provide justification on the method that you used it would be helpful I'm sure. However like you say this method is used for interview data.

I'd guess (but obviously don't know for sure) that your survey data might be quite minimal/basic if it features at the end of a more structured questionnaire and although there are similarities with many qualitative data analysis techniques, I'd imagine you'd be looking to organise your open-ended responses into something more manageable, perhaps grouping together responses reflecting a particular view.

The following article may be of help:

[Hsieh, H.F., Shannon, S. E.; **Three Approaches to Qualitative Content Analysis**, Qual Health Res November 2005 vol. 15 no. 9 1277-1288. doi: 10.1177/1049732305276687](http://qhr.sagepub.com/content/15/9/1277)